# pytest: How to access tmp_path in pytest_sessionstart()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using `pytest` to write some unit tests.

I know I can access the `tmp_path` temporary directory in any test or fixture, but is it possible to access it in the `pytest_sessionstart()` method too?

Essentially, this is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session, tmp_path):
    """Create hello.txt before any test is ran and make available to all tests"""
    p = tmp_path.join("hello.txt")
    p.write("content")
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not possible - you have access to fixtures only from other fixtures and tests. Maybe you want a session-scoped fixture instead? That would at least accomplish the task mentioned in the doc string.

Comment: Though note that you cannot use `tmp_path` in a session-scoped fixture, you need `tmp_path_factory` or `tmpdir_factory` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen, that's a good point. I don't have experience with `tmp_path_factory` but i think that could work. What's actually the difference between `pytest_sessionstart()` and a session-scoped fixture?

Comment: `pytest_sessionstart()` is called just after the session is created, session-scoped fixtures are called afterwards, but before all tests (and the part after `yield` is called after all tests in the session). And of course, you have access to other session-scoped fixtures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to create a temp file for all the tests is to use a session scoped fixture with the inbuilt tmp_path_factory fixture.

From [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-factory-fixture) :

```py
# contents of conftest.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def image_file(tmp_path_factory):
    img = compute_expensive_image()
    fn = tmp_path_factory.mktemp("data").join("img.png")
    img.save(str(fn))
    return fn


# contents of test_image.py
def test_histogram(image_file):
    img = load_image(image_file)
    # compute and test histogram
```

Comment: To use the base temporary directory directly, instead of creating a sub-directory 'data', use the undocumented: `tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp()`.